# Conf file properties not getting picked up in spring boot when running via init.d

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am running the packaged spring boot jar currently as a init.d service as per the steps in the manual https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html . Things work great but the only issue is its not able to pick up props from the conf file .
In my setup the jar file name is FooApp.jar and the conf file has also been named FooApp.conf in the same directory path.Also the contents of the conf file as below

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024M -Xms512m -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9001,server=y,suspend=n -Denv=test
RUN_ARGS=--aws.vpc.name=fooVpc--aws.stack.name=foo --info.app.version=<VERSION> --spring.profiles.active=default,test,aws
```

Could you help me if the format of the conf file is correct and why when the app spring boot is run as a linux service it doesn't pick up the configs form the apps conf file.

Thanks

Comment: Add quotes to the value? (i.e. `RUN_ARGS="..."`).

Comment: Thanks for the help @StéphaneNicoll works now :)